# How can I check if Solace replay has completed and rejoined the live data stream

Tags: java, spring, spring-jms, solace

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76666897/21324690), the codebase I am working on uses Solace's JCSMP API to trigger a replay, and uses the Spring JMS Listener annotated method to consume the replayed events.

I would like to ask, how can I check either via JMS or the Solace JCSMP Api in my spring boot application whether my client-initiated replay has completed?

I have read up from these following links that suggest that on replay completion it switches to live data stream but does not say anything about any flags or method to detect this switch.

1. [https://docs.solace.com/Features/Replay/Message-Replay-Overview.htm#:~:text=During%20replay%2C%20new%20live%20messages,Broker%20Manager%2C%20or%20SEMP%20commands](https://docs.solace.com/Features/Replay/Message-Replay-Overview.htm#:%7E:text=During%20replay%2C%20new%20live%20messages,Broker%20Manager%2C%20or%20SEMP%20commands)
2. [https://docs.solace.com/Features/Replay/Msg-Replay-Playback.htm#:~:text=What%20happens%20to%20live%20messages%20received%20with%20a%20replaying%20endpoint%20destination%3F](https://docs.solace.com/Features/Replay/Msg-Replay-Playback.htm#:%7E:text=What%20happens%20to%20live%20messages%20received%20with%20a%20replaying%20endpoint%20destination%3F)

edit: I have gotten approval to switch from JMS to the JCSMP api fully. However, I am still unable to detect any switch to live data stream from replayed messages.

Comment: I have tried this, I m not sure why but it is constantly in an inactive flow state, even after the replay is "completed" and there are no more events to be replayed

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way of knowing this. Can you elaborate on why you would need to know?

If you absolutely needed to you can capture the time you start your consumer and check the msg timestamps as they come in. Note that timestamps will be set by the clients so you'll want to ensure clocks are synced if you go this route.

Comment: thanks for responding. In my case, as the data is being replayed from solace, it could be considered that the data is incomplete, and I should not be showing the data until replay has completed because it can have different implications if a user sees the incomplete data and thinks it is current data

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. That makes sense to me. You need all the historical data before you can start allowing users to access it. If you have access to Solace support or an account team I would suggest making a feature request for adding an API event that notifies you of this.

Comment: Hmm, that’s nice to know. Though I don’t directly have access since I will have to go through my company’s solace team and only if they think it’s a valid/urgent issue before they bring it up with the solace vendor. Not only that, we will have to have a good case to make a change to production solace versions assuming this feature is added to a new version. I ll see what I can do, thanks!